# overlapping radial gradients / "light source" effect in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, radial-gradients

I'm looking to produce an effect of light sources in KineticJS.  I'm trying to accomplish this by having various objects in the background, and a layer of multiple low-alpha Rect objects filled with radial gradient patterns.

The effect is quite satisfying, and I've been playing with getting various effects by fiddling with the gradient parameters

[image: simple radial]
[image: high eccentricity radial]

The trouble is I've only managed to get one light source so far, since a second Rect on top of this one will impede visibility of the one behind it.  I'm sure there's some sort of composite operational jiggery-pokery I can carry out that will get me the union of two or more radial gradients, but I've not had much luck under my own steam.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your code with a working Codepen/jsFiddle/jsBin?